# How to make a list update constantly while running the application. VB

Tags: vb.net, winforms

How would i get my list to update all the time while my application is running instead of updating only when i start my application?

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object,
                          ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim username As String
    username = SystemInformation.UserName
    Dim filesInFolder As String
    filesInFolder= "C:\Users\" + username + "\AppData\Roaming\pictures\pics"

    Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo(filesInFolder)
    Dim aryFi As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles("*.jpg")
    Dim fi As IO.FileInfo

        For Each fi In aryFi
            list.Items.Add(fi.Name)
        Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have code to show? Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: We need more details than "Your list".  Where is the data coming from?  Have you get a database you load it from?  Is it xml? Is it pixies?

Comment: You need to give a lot more detail including showing what you have at present and explaining what the desired result would be. We don't know what you app is, how the list updates currently etc.

Comment: sorry just added some code now

Comment: i would suggest you to use an ajax function which calls a web service which would return an array to the calling ajax function and populate your list accordingly.

Comment: Personally I would look at the [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) class.

Comment: I think the OP is using Winforms not asp.

Comment: @bendataclear you are correct didnt notice form1_load...someone needs to edit his tags to include winforms

Comment: Please use `Environment.SpecialFolder` instead of hard-coding file paths.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the [FileSystemWatcher Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

> Listens to the file system change notifications and raises events when a directory, or file in a directory, changes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Timer.

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim timer as New windows.forms.timer
    AddHandler timer.Tick, Addressof MyTimerHandlersSub        
    timer.start()

    End Sub

    Private Sub MyTimerHandlersSub(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As
System.EventArgs)
       'Update Your List Here.
    End Sub
```